# Get list of results from recursive method

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion

I have this code :

```
private void SearchForDoc()
{
     try
     {
        outputtext = @"c:\temp\outputtxt";
        outputphotos = @"c:\temp\outputphotos";
        temptxt = @"c:\temp\txtfiles";
        tempphotos = @"c:\temp\photosfiles";
        if (!Directory.Exists(temptxt))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temptxt);
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(tempphotos))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempphotos);
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(outputtext))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputtext);
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(outputphotos))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputphotos);
        }
        t = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));

        ApplyAllFiles(t, ProcessFile);
        for (int i = 0; i < textfiles.Length; i++)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo((textfiles[i]));
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(temptxt);
            long dirSize = DirSize(d);

            if ((dirSize + fi.Length) <= 8388608)
                fi.CopyTo(temptxt + "\\" + fi.Name, true);
            else
                break;
        }
        Compressions("textfiles.zip", temptxt, outputtext);
```

The problem is with this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textfiles.Length; i++)
```

`textfiles` was `string[]` but now `textfiles` is no longer exists since I'm using the `ApplyAllFiles` method:

```
static void ProcessFile(string path) {/* ... */}

static void ApplyAllFiles(string folder, Action<string> fileAction)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
    {
        fileAction(file);
    }
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        try
        {
            ApplyAllFiles(subDir, fileAction);
        }
        catch
        {
            // swallow, log, whatever
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT**

In my method now i have:

```
string t = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string[] textfiles = ApplyAllFiles(t, "*.txt", ProcessFile).ToArray();
```

Then the ApplyAllFiles method:

```
static void ProcessFile(string path) {/* ... */}
        static IEnumerable<string> ApplyAllFiles(string folder, string searchPattern, Action<string> fileAction)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
            {
                fileAction(file);
                yield return file;
            }
            foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder, searchPattern))
            {
               // try
                //{
                    foreach (string file in ApplyAllFiles(subDir, searchPattern, fileAction))
                    {
                        yield return file;
                    }
               // }
               // catch
               // {
                    // swallow, log, whatever
               // }
            }
        }
```

Had to remove the try in catch yield cant be in try and catch
Second i added searchPatterns variable also in the second inner foreach loop

The result is im getting only pdf or something files not text about 25 files and only from the main dosuments directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all files processed by `ApplyAllFiles` like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ApplyAllFiles(string folder, Action<string> fileAction)
{
    IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        fileAction(file);
    }

    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        try
        {
            files = files.Concat(ApplyAllFiles(subDir, fileAction));
        }
        catch
        {
            // swallow, log, whatever
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

But this will return an `IEnumerable<string>` to turn it into a `string[]` use this:

```
var textfiles = ApplyAllFiles(t, ProcessFile).ToArray();
```

---

To only apply the specified action to certain files, you can pass in a new parameter like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ApplyAllFiles(string folder, string searchPattern, Action<string> fileAction)
{
    IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, searchPattern);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        fileAction(file);
    }

    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        try
        {
            files = files.Concat(ApplyAllFiles(subDir, searchPattern, fileAction));
        }
        catch
        {
            // swallow, log, whatever
        }
    }

    return files;
}

var textfiles = ApplyAllFiles(t, "*.txt", ProcessFile).ToArray();
```

Note however, there is already an [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) that allows you to search a directory recursively. This whole structure can probably be reduced to:

```
var textfiles = Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(var f in textfiles)
{
    ProcessFile(f);
}
```

Comment: p.s.w.g working one small sub question if i want to get only text file from the ApplyallFiles and not all files only text ?

Comment: @DanielVest How do you determine if it's a text file?

Comment: I do "*.txt" i want to filter that the List will be only with text files.

Comment: So ApplyAllFiles will return in the end a List with text files only.

Comment: @DanielVest Okay last question, do you want to apply `ProcessFile` to *all* files and just return text files, or do you want to only apply `ProcessFile` to text files?

Comment: I prefer that ProcessFile will apply already to only text files. Not all files.

Comment: pswg it didnt return for me only text file no text files at all. I also had to change this line in the ApplAllFiles: foreach (string file in ApplyAllFiles(subDir, searchPattern, fileAction))  had to add the searchPattern variable too there.

Comment: p.s.w.g updated my question please look at the EDIT** section

Comment: And p.s.w.g i dont want to use SearchOption.AllDirectories at all.

Comment: @DanielVest In your updated code you have `Directory.GetFiles(folder)`, mine has `Directory.GetFiles(folder, searchPattern)`. But I updated my answer to provide solution so you can keep your `try-catch` block there.